# JAVA Pass by reference error in method

Tags: java

I was trying to perform sorting of integers in an array and it worked fine.
But when i try to modify the program by including a "pass by reference" concept via a method, it is throwing error "cannot find symbol".

I am new to JAVA and learning by my own, Please help me with what I am doing wrong here.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Sort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Sort obj = new Sort();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, p, k, arr[];
        arr = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter the numbers for sorting \n");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            arr[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (p = 0; p < 5; p++) {
                if (arr[i] < arr[p]) {
                    /*
                     * moving the below block for swapping to a new method. k =
                     * arr[i]; arr[i]= arr[p]; arr[p]= k;
                     */

                    obj.swap(obj);
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println(arr[i]);

    }

    public void swap(Sort m) {
        m.k = m.arr[i];
        m.arr[i] = m.arr[p];
        m.arr[p] = m.k;

    }

}
```

The error I am getting is :

```
"Sort.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
      m.k = m.arr[i];
       ^
"
```

Similarly 10 such errors for other variables as well.

Comment: There is no such thing as `pass-by-reference` in java, it´s completly `pass-by-value`. In addition your class `Sort` doesn´t have a class variable `k` nor `arr`

Comment: Okay, I meant passing an object to a method and handling the changes there as i did above, but I am getting error. Am i doing something wrong there?

Comment: what error you are getting

Comment: Where do you get what error? Please be specific.

Comment: @Sam your class `Sort` doesn´t have a variable `k`, aswell as it doesn´t have a variable `arr`

Comment: `k`, `arr` don't seem to be instance variables for Sort then how could you use them the way you are doing

Comment: Hi all, I have edited my question and added the error I am getting.

Comment: I've already answered your question :)

Comment: @RossDrew Thanks, I upvoted your solution too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use index variables (`i` and `p`) that don't exist in the context you are trying to use them (inside `swap()` method body) as well as *members* of `Sort` (`k` and `arr`) which don't exist.  The scope of all these, you have limited to the method body of `main()`:-

```
public void swap(Sort m) {
    m.k = m.arr[i];      //No 'i' in swap(). No 'k' or 'arr' in 'm'(an instance of 'Sort')
    m.arr[i] = m.arr[p]; //No 'p' in swap()
    m.arr[p] = m.k;
}
```

**Short-term Solution**

Change your `swap()` method to

```
//Now accepting in i and p
public void swap(Sort m, int i, int p) {
    m.k = m.arr[i];      
    m.arr[i] = m.arr[p]; 
    m.arr[p] = m.k;
}
```

then call it like this

```
obj.swap(obj, i, p); //pass in i and p
```

and move your `Sort` variables to be accessible members of `Sort`

```
public class Sort {
  public static int k;                   //now accessible with m.k
  public static int[] arr = new int[10]; //now accessible with m.arr
...
}
```

Lastly, is it intentional that your array is 10 long but you only fill it with 5 numbers?

**Pass-by-Reference**

There is no "pass-by-reference" in Java.  Everything is passed by value.  The confusing thing is that what is passed by value is technically a reference to the object, meaning you get strange effects like you can edit the object but not reassign it.

Comment: Got it clearly. One more doubt as i am curious to know, what if I define my variables i and p also along with arr[] and k as accessible members? Can I use them directly in my swap method without being passed in my method call?

Comment: Yes but I would say they are better passed in, they are of no use anywhere but inside the loops and inside the method(s) called inside the loops.

Comment: I just tried that (what i asked above), interestingly my program did not give me any compile error but then the output was not correct! I gave 5 different numbers and my output returned the numbers in the order I inputted them. If you don't mind, I would like to ask why that happened.

Comment: Works for me. `Enter the numbers for sorting`, `10 2 4 68 8`, output=`2
4
8
10
68`

Comment: I got it, I need to use obj.i and obj.p where ever I am using them in that case. Got it, please ignore my above question :)

Comment: Oh, I see. If you are moving `i` and `p`, yes.  Please accept my answer also =D

Answer (score 0):

Solution: move the stuff back from the `swap` method to where it was.

Alternatively, provide the necessary values as parameters to `swap`.

Comment: Doesn't fix it, there's still no `k` or `arr` available to `swap`

Comment: @Ross Oh dear, that code is more messy than I realized. Thanks.